# Scene2D coordinates

Tags: java, libgdx

I use `Scene2D` functionality in my game. I have `FitViewport` with virtual screen size 1920x1080.

```
viewport = new FitViewport(AssetLoader.VIRTUAL_WIDTH, AssetLoader.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
stage = new Stage(viewport);
```

Also, there is `MyActor` class extended from `Actor` class. `MyActor` constructor:

```
public MyActor(String text, float x, float y) {
    this.text = text;

    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(AssetLoader.robotoFontFile);
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 96;
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();
    layout = new GlyphLayout();
    layout.setText(font, text);
    super.setBounds(x, y, layout.width, layout.height);

    this.debug();
    renderer = new ShapeRenderer();


    this.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log("MyActor", text + " is touched!");
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

And `MyActor` overrided `draw()` method:

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    batch.end();

    renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    this.drawDebugBounds(renderer);
    renderer.end();

    batch.begin();
    font.draw(batch, text, getX(), getY());

}
```

When running I get this:

[image: bounds strange behavior]

`InputListener` handles input only when I touch inside green rectangle in spite of the expected touch on the text.

So, where is the problem? Is `BitmapFont` `draw` method takes the position of top left corner or there is some troubles with coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add actor height solve your issue.

```
font.draw(batch, text, getX(), getY()+ getHeight());
```

But your Actor for font not good enough, you can only change position. Rotation and Scaling don't work on that.

```
private Container<Label> container;

@Override
public void create() {
    stage=new Stage();

    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(AssetLoader.robotoFontFile);
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 96;
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();  

    Label label1 = new Label("Test text", new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.BLACK));

    container=new Container<Label>(label1);
    container.setTransform(true);   // for enabling scaling and rotation
    container.size(100, 60);
    container.setOrigin(container.getWidth() / 2, container.getHeight() / 2);
    container.setPosition(100,200);
    container.setScale(3);  //scale according to your requirement

    stage.addActor(container);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.draw();
    stage.act();
}
```

And keep in mind you're creating font for each separate font Actor, that is not good, Create font once and pass it to all font Actor.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain, why scaling and rotation won't work?

Comment: when you scale or rotate then only your Actor scaled or rotated but for Font Actor, Actor is just a model and it's view is font, that will not affected

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now. Maybe, your can resolve another my problem, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613593/fitviewport-does-not-scale-actor