# FitViewport does not scale actor

Tags: java, libgdx

I have `FitViewport` with virtual screen size 1920x1080.

```
viewport = new FitViewport(AssetLoader.VIRTUAL_WIDTH, AssetLoader.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
stage = new Stage(viewport);
```

Also, there is `TimeBar` class extended from `Actor` class. `TimeBar` listing:

```
public class TimeBar extends Actor {
private Color color;
private ShapeRenderer renderer;
private float time, current;

public TimeBar() {
    color = Color.valueOf(AssetLoader.TIMEBAR_COLOR);
    renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);

    setBounds(10, 10, 1800, 10); //rectangle is wider than the screen! Why?
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    batch.end();
    renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    renderer.rect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    renderer.end();
    batch.begin();
}
}
```

I've added some logs to `render` method:

```
    Gdx.app.log("GameRenderer", "resizing: " + width + " " + height);
    Gdx.app.log("GameRenderer", "world width: " + viewport.getWorldWidth());
    Gdx.app.log("GameRenderer", "stage width: " + stage.getWidth());
    Gdx.app.log("GameRenderer", "Time bar width: " + timeBar.getWidth());
```

They said:

```
GameRenderer: world width: 1920.0
GameRenderer: stage width: 1920.0
GameRenderer: Time bar width: 1800.0
```

But rectangle is wider then the screen, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating Stage with predefined Viewport, so projection matrix of stage's batch is defined by stage viewport but when you create ShapeRenderer then projection matrix is defined by `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and by `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()`

write these two lines in `draw()` method.

```
renderer.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
renderer.setTransformMatrix(batch.getTransformMatrix());
```

Or you can use this class

https://github.com/itsabhiaryan/gdx-utils/blob/master/gdx-utils/src/com/ng/gdxutils/actor/ShapeRendererActor.java

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Stared your repo, will use in future